# how to find the exact version of the installed AIR SDK

Tags: air

The AIR SDK is usually only referenced by major and minor version number, but there are important differences in the numbers way to the right.
How can I inspect my installed SDK and know for certain which *exact* version it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on Windows:

1. Navigate to the location of the AIR SDK.
2. Open the /bin/ subdirectory. You should see a file named adl.exe.
3. Right-click on adl.exe and select Properties from the context menu.
4. In the Properties dialog, click the Details tab.

The Details tab contains a property named "File Version" with a value that shows the full version of the AIR SDK (e.g., 3.5.0.1060).

If you're on a Mac (or on Windows), you could just create a bare-bones AIR app and add this line of ActionScript:

```
trace(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion);
```

When you test the file in your IDE of choice, you should see the full AIR SDK version in your IDE's output panel.

Answer (score 1):

For the most definitive answer, directly ask AIR SDK what version it is (`adt.jar` is the AIR SDK's packager):

```
java -jar C:\air_sdk\lib\adt.jar -version
```

Which prints the full version number:

```
3.9.0.1030
```

How to find the `adt.jar` file on your system? Often you'll have an environment variable set pointing to your AIR SDK, such as `AIR_HOME` or `AIR_SDK_FOLDER`, so you can use that in your command:

Windows:

```
java -jar %AIR_SDK_FOLDER%\lib\adt.jar -version
```

Or on a Mac / Linux:

```
java -jar $AIR_SDK_FOLDER/lib/adt.jar -version
```

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X

Open the /Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/Info.plist text file and locate the CFBundleVersionentry. The corresponding string entry represents the version of AIR, for example:

CFBundleVersion
    26.0.0.127

https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/determine-version-air-runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

From Mac
Write the following console command to check the current version of Adobe AIR SDK:
%AIR_SDK_FOLDER%/bin/adl -version

Comment: I tried this with both a Flex SDK and an AIR SDK and got this result :
    application descriptor not found

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the above, it's adt, not adl to spew the version number to the commandline on Mac (and probably Windows too).

So:

%AIR_SDK_FOLDER%/bin/adt -version